# Cannot set header after they have been sent, in res.send()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing down my server and in the login method it break telling me that i can not set header after they have been sent. But the purpose was only to return a json. Thanks you.

This is my piece of code, i'm using bcrypt to make more secure user password.

```
function login(req,res,next){
if(req.headers.email && req.headers.password){
    if(req.headers.email.indexOf('@')>=0 || req.headers.password.length>0){
        var emailz = req.headers.email;
        var passwordz = req.headers.password;
        user.findOne({email:emailz}).then(result=>{
            console.log(result);
            if(!result){
                return res.status(401).send({error:'userDoesNotExists'});
            }
            bcrypt.compare(passwordz,result.password,function(err,same){
                if(!same){
                    return res.status(401).send({error:'PasswordIsNotCorrect'});
                }
                var utente = {id: result.id, username:result.username, email:result.email, name:result.name, surname:result.surname};
                console.log('Token',jwt.encode(utente,config.TOKEN_SECRET,'HS256'));
                next();
                return res.status(200).redirect('/');
            })

        })

    }
}
return res.status(401).send({error:'EmailOrPasswordAreEmpty'});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user.findOne` is most likely doing a database lookup, and is therefor async. Your bottom return will fire, no matter what happens inside that if-statement. Put an else around the last return.

```
function login(req,res,next){
if(req.headers.email && req.headers.password){
    if(req.headers.email.indexOf('@')>=0 || req.headers.password.length>0){
        var emailz = req.headers.email;
        var passwordz = req.headers.password;
        user.findOne({email:emailz}).then(result=>{
            console.log(result);
            if(!result){
                return res.status(401).send({error:'userDoesNotExists'});
            }
            bcrypt.compare(passwordz,result.password,function(err,same){
                if(!same){
                    return res.status(401).send({error:'PasswordIsNotCorrect'});
                }
                var utente = {id: result.id, username:result.username, email:result.email, name:result.name, surname:result.surname};
                console.log('Token',jwt.encode(utente,config.TOKEN_SECRET,'HS256'));
                next();
                return res.status(200).redirect('/');
            })

        })

    }
} else {
    return res.status(401).send({error:'EmailOrPasswordAreEmpty'});
}
}
```